# Unreal Engine 4: How to make blueprints with FBX chunks of DestructibleMesh?

Tags: fbx, unreal-4, unreal

Into my project I imported a .FBX file that contains several small pieces. It's a helicopter rotor with about 220 parts. I now want to write blueprints with these pieces but not only with the whole thing.
I already created a DestructibleMesh out of the initial StaticMesh and imported the FBX chunks, so the detail pieces are known to Unreal and I can explode them properly.

During FBX import I also found the option to NOT group the parts into the root object but make a StaticMesh out of EVERY part. Then of course blueprints can be done with all rotor parts but the relative position of the parts to each other is not given anymore and I would have to reorder them from scratch - which is VERY much work in this case.

Does someone have a good solution for that? With the spare parts of the rotor, some gasification tasks should be made. For example exchanging two parts or "repair" something.

Thanks in advance!